# I'm trying to use the HTML5 Web Audio API to create an equalizer type graphic, but the data is never brought into the MediaElementSourc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm trying to use the HTML5 Web Audio API to create an equalizer type graphic, but for some reason the data is never brought into the `MediaElementSource`.

```
$('.table').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    if ($(this) != $('.table tr:first-child')) {
        var src = $(this).children().first().attr('data-src');
        var audio = new Audio();
        audio.src = src;
        audio.controls = true;
        $('.file-playlist').append(audio);
        console.log(audio);         
        audio.load();
        audio.play();
        context = new webkitAudioContext();
        console.log(context);
        analyser = context.createAnalyser();
        console.log(analyser);
        source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
        console.log(source);
        source.connect(analyser);
        console.log(source);
        analyser.connect(context.destination);
        console.log(analyser);
        rafCallback();
    }
});
```

In the function above I have created an audio element and used that as the source for the context's `MediaElementSource` however there is some issue that I cannot find because in the console, the `activeSourceCount` attribute of the AudioContext is always 0, which means that it never received the audio element that I gave it as a parameter.

EDIT:

I modified my code according to what idbehold said; however, now I have 2 errors, an `InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11` on the `source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);` line, and a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'frequencyBinCount' of undefined` at the line `var freqByteData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);` Additionally, the MediaElementSource still has 0 activeSourceCounts.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var context = new webkitAudioContext();
    console.log(context);
    var audio;
    var source;
    $('.table').on('click', 'tr', function() {
        if ($(this) != $('.table tr:first-child')) {
            var src = $(this).children().first().attr('data-src');
            if (audio) {
                audio.remove();
                audio = new Audio();
                audio.src = src;
                audio.controls = true;
                $('.file-playlist').append(audio);
                console.log(audio);
                audio.addEventListener("canplay", function(e) {
                    analyser = context.createAnalyser();
                    console.log(analyser);
                    source.disconnect();
                    source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
                    console.log(source);
                    source.connect(analyser);
                    console.log(source);
                    analyser.connect(context.destination);
                    console.log(analyser);
                    audio.load();
                    audio.play();
                }, false);
            }
            else {
                audio = new Audio();
                audio.src = src;
                audio.controls = true;
                $('.file-playlist').append(audio);
                console.log(audio);
                audio.addEventListener("canplay", function(e) {
                    analyser = (analyser || context.createAnalyser());
                    console.log(analyser);
                    source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
                    console.log(source);
                    source.connect(analyser);
                    console.log(source);
                    analyser.connect(context.destination);
                    console.log(analyser);
                    audio.load();
                    audio.play();
               }, false);
            }
        }
        rafCallback();
    });
});
```

EDIT 2:

in my rafCallback() function, I noticed that the data from the Uint8Array was never being processed, so I added the `getByteFrequencyData(analyser.frequencyBinCount);` which fixed everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only create a single `AudioContext` per window and you should be waiting until the audio's `canplay` event fires before setting up your `MediaElementSource`. You should also be disconnecting the `MediaElementSource` when you're finished using it.

Here's an example that I used to answer a similar question: http://jsbin.com/acolet/1/

Comment: Isn't there only one `AudioContext` in my code? What is the `canplay` event and how do I use it? How do I disconnect the `MediaElementSource`?

Comment: You're creating a new `AudioContext` every time your click event fires. Follow the example code here: http://jsbin.com/acolet/1/edit

Comment: Your answer will be downvoted if you don't provide an explanation as to what process the link follows, just providing a link doesn't do me any good if I don't understand it, and you didn't either of my other questions.

Comment: I cannot dumb it down anymore than I have already. The answers to your questions should be easy to see in the example I provided. I'm not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: What is the difference between the `audio.load();` call and the event listener for the 'canplay' event?

Comment: Try putting the `audio.load()` outside (right before) the `audio.addEventListener('canplay', handler)`.

Comment: Also, inside your `if (audio) {` statement make sure the line assigning `analyser` looks like this: `analyser = (analyser || context.createAnalyser())`

Comment: Oh, and your `rafCallback()` should be after `audio.play()`, inside the `canplay` event handler.

Comment: I made those changes and now I have no errors, but the MediaElementSource still has 0 activeSourceCounts. Any ideas? I would think this means that the `source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);` line isn't processing properly for some reason, but then again the Mozilla developer network docs for the MediaElementSourceNode isn't working (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaElementAudioSourceNode)

Comment: In your jsbin, when I put in console.log(sourceNode) after you created it, your sourceNode also had 0 activeSourceCounts, so I'm not sure how yours and mine differ.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for the help. If you're curious about the problem check my EDIT 2.